# Posting to server via C# with RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, restsharp

I've been trying all night to get the following REST response in c#. The url is

http://domain/WebServices/api/AdvisingApi/Authenticate?flashlineID=jdister1&password=password

I used a site called https://www.hurl.it/ to ensure that this endpoint was working at it is getting me back a response as expected. However, in my C# code I keep getting a

**"{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"**

as the response in my RestSharp request. Here is the relevant code:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://domain/WebServices/api/AdvisingApi/");
        var request = new RestRequest("Authenticate", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("flashlineID", userName);
        request.AddParameter("password", password);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because I built the request in the same manner (I think) that is is sent with Hurl.it. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry stupid question and poor research on my part. Contacted the provider and recognized that the expected type was xml.